# Eagle UI: updating silkscreen of library component

Tags: eaglecad

I just finished a schematic in the free version of Eagle that contains 20+ 0402 resistors and about a hundred 0805 capacitors.

I switched over to the board layout and found that the footprint of all these passives contains the part value, which I don't want as there isn't room on the PCB.

So, I edited the library and removed the ">VALUE" text. I then ran library->update all. However, the value text was not removed from any of the footprints.

If I right click on the component -> "open footprint" it shows me the updated footprint with silkscreen text removed. But the actual footprint in the board layout is not updated.

How do I fix this without having to manually change every. single. footprint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

>VALUE is a placeholder for text that you can assign to a component with the value tool. You should not remove this field from the library. As it may be helpful in the assembly drawing.

Instead, just hide layer 27 and 28, and also omit them when generating the silkscreen gerber files.